# Join two datasets, both with points

Tags: python, geopandas

I have two csv files with points. One dataset of schools (lat, lon and school name) and one with coordinates of houses (lat, lon and houseid).

I want to list all houses which are within a 500 meters radius from a school.

I really can't figure out how to do a spatial join with geopandas in Python. Can someone please help me?

```
schools.csv
56.039484;14.164114;Parkskolan
56.029687;14.159337;Centralskolan


houses.csv
56.039240;14.165066;1
56.039008;14.166709;2
56.038608;14.169420;3
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample data?

Comment: Sure, updated now, @joris

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main steps to get the solutions:

1. read the 2 data files into dataframes
2. set CRS('epsg:4326') and create Point geometry from (lat,long) for both dataframes
3. for `schools` dataframe, convert CRS to UTMzone 33N
4. do buffering (radius=500m) on `schools` dataframe
5. on `schools` dataframe, perform and set the 500m buffer as new `geometry`
6. do proper spatial join between `houses` and `schools` in the common CRS
7. get result in `houses_joined` dataframe

Here is the working code:

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon

# School data
# -----------
# read `schools.csv`, data are in (lat,long); 'epsg:4326'
#
# lat;lon;school_name
# 56.039484;14.164114;Parkskolan
# 56.029687;14.159337;Centralskolan
df_schools = pd.read_csv('schools.csv', na_values=['NaN'], sep=';')

# create Point geometry objects from (lon,lat)
sch_geom = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(df_schools.lon, df_schools.lat)]
# set initial coordinate ref system, and geometry column to the dataframe
gdf_schools = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df_schools, crs={'init': 'epsg:4326'}, geometry=sch_geom)

# convert CRS from (lat,long) to UTMzone 33N
# and get new dataframe: gdf_schools_utm33N
gdf_schools_utm33N = gdf_schools.to_crs(crs="+proj=utm +zone=33 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs")
# Note: crs="..." can be replaced by epsg=32633

# do buffering, radius: 500m
gdf_schools_utm33N['buffer_geometry'] = gdf_schools_utm33N.geometry.buffer(500)

# rename `geometry` -> `original_geometry`; `buffer_geometry` -> geometry
# .. and set column `geometry` as the default geometry data of the geodataframe.
gdf_schools_utm33N = gdf_schools_utm33N.rename(
    columns={'geometry':'original_geometry', 'buffer_geometry':'geometry'}).set_geometry('geometry')

# Houses data
# -----------
# read `houses.csv`, data are in (lat,long); 'epsg:4326'

# lat;lon;houseid
# 56.039240;14.165066;1
# 56.039008;14.166709;2
# 56.038608;14.169420;3
# 56.046108;14.171420;4

df_houses = pd.read_csv('houses.csv', na_values=['NaN'], sep=';')
# I add the 4th house that is too far away from all schools
# The 4th house: 56.046108  14.171420   4

# create Point geometry for the houses, and init CRS
hs_geom = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(df_houses.lon, df_houses.lat)]
gdf_houses = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df_houses, crs={'init': 'epsg:4326'}, geometry=hs_geom)

# options: plot the schools' buffers and all the houses
ax = gdf_schools_utm33N.plot(color='lightgray', edgecolor='green', alpha=0.5)
gdf_houses.to_crs(epsg=32633).plot(ax=ax, color='red')

# ******* Spatial Join *****************
# houses data frame needs CRS conversion
hss = gdf_houses.to_crs(epsg=32633)
# do spatial join of houses(points) ~ schools(circles of 500m radius)
houses_joined = gpd.sjoin(hss, gdf_schools_utm33N, op='within', how='inner')
# print out the successful joined rows (house_id, school_names)

# this prints house_id + school_name 
houses_joined[['houseid','school_name']]

# Output: house_id, school_name
# 1    Parkskolan
# 2    Parkskolan
# 3    Parkskolan
```

The resulting plot:

[image]